# How to make AppendTo faster

Tags: performance-tuning

Function `AppendTo` seems to be very slow for generating a lot of scenarios, is there any chance to change it and make it faster?

```
alphaxt= 100; betaxt=130; 
     q=RandomReal[{0,1},106]
        fun[n0_, q_] := 
         Module[{DD = {}, t = 41, j, a = alphaxt, b = betaxt},
           For[j = 0, j <= t - 1, j++, 
           AppendTo[DD, 
            Min[RandomInteger[
              NegativeBinomialDistribution[a, 
               b/((n0 - Total[DD])*q[[66 + j]] + b)]], n0 - Total[DD]]]]; 
          DD]

SeedRandom[123];
 Map[fun[5000, q] &, Range[5000]]
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Table[]`?

Comment: because of the overflow of memory

Comment: But you are then gradually forming `DD` anyway…

Comment: I typically use Associations now instead of Lists with AppendTo, as they scale better.  In this case replacing the list with an Association does not change the timing.  I'm inclined to believe that list appending is not the rate determining step in this code.

Answer (score 4):

As J.M. has pointed out: using `Table[]` is a better idea, or else i modified your code a little bit with the use of `Reap[]` and `Sow[]` functions. It is on average 12 seconds faster:

```
alphaxt = 100; betaxt = 130;
q = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 106];
fun[n0_, q_] := Reap@Module[{t = 41, j, a = alphaxt, b = betaxt},
DD = 0;
For[j = 0, j <= t - 1, j++,
 DD += 
  Sow[Min[RandomInteger[
     NegativeBinomialDistribution[a, 
      b/((n0 - DD)*q[[66 + j]] + b)]], n0 - DD]]
 ];
];

Map[fun[5000, q] &, Range[5000]]
```